# CSS grid not affected by padding-bottom

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout

I'm using CSS grid to position a dynamic number of elements into rows using grid-auto-rows.

However the last element is always placed against the bottom of the page irrespective of any padding applied to the grid container (padding is applied to the top, left & right but not to bottom).

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

https://codepen.io/wrgt1/pen/XWjEwXX

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-auto-rows: 25%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 50px;
}

.item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's a chrome issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue in both Chrome and Safari unfortunately @TemaniAfif

Comment: yes all webkit browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acutally, (just like @Shristi mentioned) the problem happens because the grid-container does not reach the bottom of the items. this happens because of the grid-auto-rows which is set to 25%. After the fourth row this fills the 100%, everything else just moves out of the container. So you should change your code as follows:

```
.grid {
  // box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-auto-rows: 250px; // change this!
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 50px; // use this for the spacing in between
  padding: 50px; // use this for the spacing top, bottom, left and right of the grid
}
```

the working example: [here](https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/YzGabvv)

Comment: Great, thanks so much! Does it mean that it's impossible to use a percentage value for grid-auto-rows?

Comment: aparently you've found the problem where it doesn't work :-)

Comment: It makes sense that percentage isn't working if you have a dynamic amount of grid-elements inside a grid container. You always have only 100% available. If that space is filled up, there's no more space to assign. If all rows should be the same height, one could also use `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr)` this way, all rows will be the same height as the tallest grid-element in that grid-container.
Percentage would work if you have e.g. 4 grid-rows with 25% each (equals 100% height).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the height of your grid is less than it's contents. Add `height` to your grid and `margin-bottom` instead of padding. Hope this might help

```
.grid {
width: 100%;
display: grid;
grid-auto-flow: row;
grid-auto-rows: 25%;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
padding: 50px;
height: 100%;
margin-bottom: 50px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it causes issues with scroll [Codepen](https://codepen.io/wrgt1/pen/XWjEwxM)

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes padding does not work in HTML so in that case, you can either make div or use the br tag.

```
<div class="spacing" style="padding-bottom: 100px;"> 
// or do br where you want it.
<br>
```